# How to get count of relation field in parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

`GameScore` object have one `Relation` field named `Badges`.
How I can get count of all objects in this relation in query:

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var object = results[i];
      alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('playerName'));
    }
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

I need something like:

```
object.Badges.count
```

or

```
object.Badges.length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Parse.Relation` object is actually a query description that will return the objects in that relation, so for this case you'd need to run another query for each `GameScore`:

```
query.find().then(function (gameScores) {
    alert("Successfully retrieved " + gameScores.length + " scores.");
    var countPromises = gameScores.map(function (gs) {
        // the following executes a count() query, which is severely penalized by Parse
        return gs.get('Badges').query().count()
            .then(function (count) {
                // this extra step is to add the retrieved count as an extra property to the GameSccore object,
                // instead of returning only the counts
                gs.count = count; 
                return gs;
            });
    });
    return Parse.Promise.when(countPromises);
}).then(function () {
    var gameScoresWithBadgeCount = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}).fail(function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
});
```

This causes a lot of extra round trips (I assume you're on a browser environment because of `alert()`), and calls `count()` queries which are additionally limited by Parse.

What I can recommend you is to keep a count cache as an extra field on the `GameScore` class, and update it accordingly through CloudCode hooks. Alternatively, you can try to avoid the `Relation` and make the equivalent [using an Array field](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#relations-using-an-array) if possible, through which you can always [include](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_include) the related Badges if needed or get their count without querying for them at all!

Comment: So every query for relation is one request to parse right?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the CloudCode querying and saving to keep a count cache also counts as individual queries, but hopefully they'd be much smaller in number (only running when Badges are saved), instead of on every time you want to show a count (also big perceived performance hit when displaying the web page).

Comment: So as I understand if I use `Array` filed with simple `include` I will get all objects, but what I am loosing if change my relation field with array as in my case this is not small change due to many clients :( - I like first suggestion more.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, tougher than one would hope.  It requires another asynch trip through the data, so your callback form can do it, but isn't really up to the job.  Here it is with promises...

```
// return a promise that's fulfilled with a badges count for the passed GameScore
function badgeCountOfGameScore(gameScore) {
    var relation = gameScore.get("Badges");  // it must have a relation col called Badges for this to work
    return relation.query.find().then(function(results) {
        return results.length;
    });
}
```

Now your original function redone with promises (and underscore to better handle arrays)...

```
var _ = require("underscore");

function bunchOfBadgeCounts() {
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
    var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.equalTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
    return query.find().then(function(results) {
        alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
        var promises = _.map(results, function(object) {
            return badgeCountOfGameScore(object);
        });
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
    }).then(function() {
        alert("Counts = " + JSON.stringify(_.toArray(arguments)));
    }, function (error) {
        alert("Error = " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```